# Can I simplify a condition with short-circuit call chain in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, short-circuiting

Can this code snippet be simplified on the second line?

From:

```dart
GetBuilder<ProductController>(builder: (productController) {
    return productController.reviewedProductList == null || productController.reviewedProductList.length != 0
    ? CategoryDrinksView(productController: productController, isPopular: true)
    : SizedBox();
})
```

To:

```dart
GetBuilder<ProductController>(builder: (productController) {
    return productController.reviewedProductList?.length != 0
    ? CategoryDrinksView(productController: productController, isPopular: true)
    : SizedBox();
})
```

The IDE doesn't return any errors and everything seems to work, but I would like to know if this is common in Dart and can be considered good practice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea. You may get a 'NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null' error, if the value of reviewedProductList was null. So keep the double checking

Comment: I don't think it will trigger an error as `?` will unwrap the optional value. If the `reviewedProductList` is `null` then it will become `null != 0` and returns true which will eventually returns CategoryDrinksView. It has the exact same result as the original code.